# How to show Profile image rather than Name in SharePoint 2013 online suite bar (Top of Bar)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to show user profile rather than display name on top bar of SharePoint (Suite Bar) currently it is displaying the display name of the user. Please see screenshot below.

[image: Image showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery and _spPageContextInfo.

[UserLoginName]=  _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName

HTML image source
"/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=[UserLoginName]"